# Problema con obtención de datos de MySql a Android

Tags: android, json, mysqli, soap, ksoap

Buenos días compañeros, tengo una pequeña cuestión en cuanto a poder llenar un ListView con datos de MySql, en general ya tengo todo lo necesario para poder obtener los datos pero al parecer cuando corro la aplicacion no me muestra ningun dato.
Aclaración, ya tengo el query bien y me muestra los datos por medio del servicio Web. (Anexo también el codigo del servicio web)

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.DAO.DaoEmpresas;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.R;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.adaptadores.AdapterEmpresas;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.adaptadores.AdapterSolicitudNis;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.adaptadores.ConsultarDatos;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.items.ItemEmpresas;
import com.ejemplo.alexis_caballero.sigc11app.items.ItemSolicitudNis;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.kobjects.util.Strings;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Datos extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ListView lstEmpresas;
    public ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myItemEp;
    public AdapterEmpresas myAdapterE;


    //Conexion ws
    private String ip = "10.169.6.189";
    private final String URL_SERVICE = "http://"+ip+"/sigc11appws/server.php#";
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://"+ip+"/sigc11appws/";
    private String METHOD_NAME = "";
    private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;


    private SoapObject request;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope envelo;
    private HttpTransportSE transport;


    private PropertyInfo empresa = null;

    ProgressDialog dialogAsynk;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_datos);

        lstEmpresas = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstEmpresas);
        myItemEp = new ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>();

        myAdapterE = new AdapterEmpresas(this,myItemEp);
        lstEmpresas.setAdapter(myAdapterE);
        registerForContextMenu(lstEmpresas);

    }


    //***********Metodo para obtener las EMPRESAS*********//
    public ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> getAllEmpresas(String params){
        METHOD_NAME = "getRegistros";
        SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

        ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> myArrayWSE = new ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>();
        try {
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            empresa = new PropertyInfo();
            empresa.setName("empresa");
            empresa.setValue(params);
            empresa.setType(String.class);

            request.addProperty(empresa);

            envelo = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelo.dotNet=false;

            transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_SERVICE);
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelo);

            String resultadoWS = (String) envelo.getResponse();

            Type tipo = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>>(){}.getType();

            Gson convertidoJson = new Gson();

            myArrayWSE = convertidoJson.fromJson(resultadoWS, tipo);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myArrayWSE;
    }

    //****************Tarea Asyncrona para trabajar segundo plano obtencion de empresas**********//
    class AsyncronoEmp extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> doInBackground(String... params) {
            return getAllEmpresas(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialogAsynk = ProgressDialog.show(Datos.this,"","espera",true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemEmpresas> itemEmpresases) {
            super.onPostExecute(itemEmpresases);
            dialogAsynk.dismiss();
        }
    }


function getRegistros($empresa){
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbcompinfra');
if($mysqli-> connect_errno) {
    die("Fallo la conexión".$mysqli->mysqli_connect_errno().")".$mysqli->mysqli_connect_errno());

}

$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM concesionario ORDER BY id");

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $empresaArray [] = array('id'=>$fila[0],
        'nombre'=>$fila[1]);
}

$arrayJson = json_encode($empresaArray);

return new soapval('return', 'xsd:string', $arrayJson);

$resultado->close();
```

}

Comment: No estas llamando el proceso que llena el Adapter, en este caso el Asynctask AsyncronoEmp !

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahora checo eso :)

Comment: Intenté llamar el proceso pero se detiene la aplicación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creaste el servicio web con alguna libreria?. Te digo,por que yo tuve que crear un servicio en php con una libreria soap para que en android yo pueda consumirlo. Eso

Comment: Si, mi servicio esta hecho en php con la librería SOAP

Comment: Añadí el codigo de la funcion, es en PHP y muchas gracias por ayudarme :)